# custom css in one page

Tags: pages, css, widget-text

I am trying to add custom css to wordpress page. Which is trying to load an image from the gallery for some reason though certain parts of the css are not working. Not sure if this has to do with the css or wordpress. Here is the css that i am trying to add and its not working:

I tried changing the font size which doesn't work, it does let me change the font family but not the size

```
@import "url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif)";
.widgettitle{
font-family: 'Bree Serif';
font-size: 150px;
}
```

Now if i try to add a background image nothing shows up:

```
.widgettitle{
background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/small_pic.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#sidebarSubnav h3` is not letting your Custom CSS to work since it already contains `!important` for its style properties.

Place your code below the above selectors or load the custom css file after the default stylesheet.

Comment: thank you for your quick response, but that still doesn't work

Comment: Share the link of your page.

Comment: Answer updated, Brad.

Comment: is there a way to override

Comment: Place your code below the above selectors or load the custom css file after the default stylesheet.

Comment: are you sure there is an important there, because i just opened up the style.css and this is what i see in there for that section     #sidebarSubnav h3{
    margin: 3px 0 0;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    background: transparent url(../images/heading_underline.png) repeat-x scroll 0 100%;
}